# How do Devas from deva loka help us humans in bhuloka?

Tags: gods, lokas

If Devas are in Deva loka and we humans live in bhuloka, then how they will help us? please explain.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong if you accept God as antaryami i.e. inside than all privara devatha is also inside doing different action for jiva under the commend of antaryami. Like manas is controlled by Rudra(Chandra), vak by sesha, shravana by garuda, chackshu (seeing) by surya.

Comment: @harishandroid can you elaborate your Q little bit?...few gods hv Vimanas and few Vahanas and few can go with the speed of mind and few can manifest anywhere...now what is your exact question? is it how gods know we need their help? or is it how they come to Bhuloka after knowing their help is needed? one example is [how lord helped Gajendra](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/8/3/)..may be you can reframe ur Q properly after reading that..

Comment: @prasannaragothaman.Like manas is controlled by Rudra(Chandra). yes i can understand your answer antaryami. Please explain me that devas are controlling us and also they are also sitting in deva looka at same time and also please explain that they have suksma sarira .

Comment: they provide rain (Indra), water (varuna), air (vayu), food (bhoomi), warmth & health (sun), medicines (moon). most modern people think these happen 'naturally'. they might as well say it happens 'blahkaflaka;, which is just a fancy word for 'i don't know who is behind it'. if someone asks me who sends me the automatic traffic tickets, i might also as well say 'they just happen naturally' if I don't know that the police setup this automated system.

Comment: That is difference between devas and normal human they can present themselves in multiple places biggest example us prana means vayu when prana stops I.e. breathing person is dead pranath vayur jathage thveneva Pratheksam brahmas this sloka is in shanti  mantra

Answer (score 1):

The main way the Devas help humanity is by causing rainfall, as the Vishnu Purana [describes](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp040.htm):

> By sacrifices, the Devas are nourished, and by the rain which they
>   bestow, mankind is supported.