# What are Gods doing now?

Tags: gods, philosophy, belief

We humans can’t sit at one place, keep thinking a lot and want to roam around. So, what will the be gods be doing? We have heard God is Omnipresent, how? Doesn’t he travel and visit places like us? What is his schedule?

The question could sound silly and may bring laughs, but request for genuine answers.

Comment: Don’t he travel? - There are extensive accounts of Gods roaming on the earth in our Puranas as well as in itihasa like Mahabharata and Ramayana so this question doesn't arise at first place. Secondly they do not only roam around earth but also to other worlds like in various lokas and in heaven. - What is his schedule?- This question is unanswerable cause nobody knows  and will be knowing that for sure.

Comment: But one thing we surely know is that he is present everywhere and doing his work of creation -preservation and destruction quite well. That is his schedule for eternity.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar - We know that, all those you are referring to context of past. The question targeting present...

Comment: The question is genuine and piques the reader’s curiosity. However as per HSE Guidelines, what God would be doing presently (not in past as **mentioned in scriptures**) this would not result in an answer backed by scriptural reference. It would thus result in the answer being opinion based.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31815/how-do-devas-from-deva-loka-help-us-humans-in-bhuloka Please read my comments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Devas from deva loka help us humans in bhuloka?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31815/how-do-devas-from-deva-loka-help-us-humans-in-bhuloka)

Comment: The gods are creating their own life just as you do now.